# Developing an Android App. But cannot run emulator nor real device (Windows 7)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to developing an Android App using Android Studio. I've been following this example app on their website: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice

The problem is, when I try to run using the emulator or my real device (Samsung S5) using the instructions on that link, I still couldn't find my device. I get an error when using the emulator that would take 10 minutes to load on my 2 GB RAM computer (only to fail).

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument (in red text)
```

Other considerations:
 1. My processor is AMD and not Intel, so the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) doesn't work for me.
 2. I used the Nexus 5 emulator device with API level 21. I tried it with Nexus 6 emulator device with API level 23. No luck on both.
 3. I've placed my Samsung S5 device on Debugging Mode but it never showed up on the "connected device" area when running the app.

I've searched for other questions relating to it. But my luck has run out. The fact that I got a slow computer adds to the bad luck.

Comment: Did you enable the developer options in your physical device's settings? 2GB RAM is not quite enough for an Emulator (even if it starts, it's gonna be slow as hell :/ )

Comment: No. 2GB is the RAM of my computer not the one I placed on the emulator. I placed 1000 MB on the emulator. I pressed "Build number" 7 times to enable the developer options on my Samsung S5 yet on Android Studio, my device doesn't appear. Just the emulator, but that doesn't work either.

By the way, does the app appear on the emulator's menu or at the home screen?

Comment: It appears in the "all apps" section. Hm, try to search about your physical device, we've had similar problems with a Meizu phone, though my Samsung Grand Neo seemed to work. Maybe you need to install some drivers, dunno, can't quite remember... Try to search :/

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing these problems due to allocation of excessive amount of RAM for the virtual device which wont be available for the device.

set it to something like 1024MB or 768MB and try again.